# How can I display more items on a button click?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue3, and I'm trying to load more projects when a button is clicked. So I have the following array of objects in store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const useProjectsStore = defineStore({
  id: 'projects',
  state: () => {
    return {
      projects: [
        {
          id: uuidv4(),
          imgUrl: lightImg,
          name: 'use this',
          description:
            'track of this',
          socialLinks: [
            {
              link: 'https://github.com',
              icon: githubIcon,
            },
            {
              link: 'www.google.ro',
              icon: mediumIcon,
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: uuidv4(),
          imgUrl: recogn,
          name: 'deep lear',
          description:
            'I tried my best',
          socialLinks: [
            {
              link: 'links',
              icon: githubIcon,
            },
          ],
        },
        ... 
        {},
        {},
      ],
    };
  },
});
```

I'm importing the following item from the store and trying to do manipulation:

```
<script setup>
/*
  imports
*/
import { useProjectsStore } from '@/stores/projects';
import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

/*
  store
*/

const storeProjects = useProjectsStore();

/*
  load more items
*/
const maxProjectsShown = ref(3);
const step = ref(3);

// a computed ref
const visibleProjects = computed(() => {
  return storeProjects.projects.value.slice(0, maxProjectsShown);
});
</script>
```

Here is the template where I'm trying the iteration:

```
    <div
      class="app__projects__container"
      v-for="(project, index) in visibleProjects"
    >
        {{ project }}
    </div>

      <div class="app__projects__showMoreButton">
      <button @click="maxProjectsShown += step">show more reviews</button>
    </div>
```

The issue here is that I cannot get data from the visibileProjects array of objs. Any idea?

Comment: Does the objects render correctly at the beginning (before you click the button) or it is broken from the start?

Comment: it’s broken from the start.

Comment: Could you try to change your computed in the way I suggested in the answer?

Comment: Can you take a look over the following question: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/why-the-text-isnt-updated-in-vue3/131169 ?

Comment: Sure, can you ask your question here? I  do not have account there.

Comment: Yup. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72976092/why-the-text-isn-t-updated-in-vue3

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not have to use .value when refer to content of project array, but you have to use it when refer to maxProjectsShown value

```
const visibleProjects = computed(() => {
  return storeProjects.projects.slice(0, maxProjectsShown.value);
});
```

Comment: I know that. Was just for testing purposes. The solution isn't working. The object isn't displayed after trying to slice it. Please read the question!