# Why the text isn’t updated in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, store

I’m trying to display a name dynamically, but I get the same name forEach element. What I’m trying to do is:

```
<template>
  <div class="app__projects">
    <div
      class="app__projects__container"
      v-for="project in visibleProjects"
      :key="project.id"
      :id="project.id"
    >
      <div class="app__projects__image">
        <img
          :src="project.imgUrl"
          alt="Project Image"
          width="570"
          height="320"
          loading="lazy"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="app__projects__content">
        <h3>{{ project.name }}</h3>
        <p>
          {{ project.description }}
        </p>
        <a
          :href="project.link"
          target="_blank"
          class="app__projects__content-btn"
        >
          {{ displayNameButton }}
        </a>
        <hr class="app__projects__content--spacer" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <button
      v-if="showMoreProjectsButton"
      class="app__projects__showMoreButton"
      @click="loadMoreProjects"
    >
      show more projects
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

On the  I'm trying to display a name dynamically, and all the time the same name is displayed, but I want to display the name based on the computed property that I wrote below.

Here is the visibleProjects:

```
const visibleProjects = computed(() => {
  return storeProjects.projects.slice(0, maxProjectsShown.value);
});
```

I’m trying to iterate through an array of objects from the store like:

```
const displayNameButton = computed(() => {
  const isObjPresent = storeProjects.projects.find((o => o.wordpress === 'yes')).wordpress;
  console.log(isObjPresent);
  if (isObjPresent === 'yes') return 'See Website';
  else if (!isObjPresent) return 'See code';
})
```

The array of objects from the store is:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const useProjectsStore = defineStore({
  id: 'projects',
  state: () => {
    return {
      projects: [
        {
          id: uuidv4(),
          imgUrl: lightImg,
          name: 'use this',
          description:
            'track of this',
          wordpress: false,
        },
        {
          id: uuidv4(),
          imgUrl: recogn,
          name: 'deep lear',
          description:
            'I tried my best',
          wordpress: ‘yes’,
        },
        ... 
        {},
        {},
      ],
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you show a little more code of your template, because right now there is no iteration - and I assume there is some if you have written that __for each__ element you have the same outcome

Comment: I just updated the template for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is with your **computed property**. It will always return the same value because there is no input based on which the function can determine which string should it returns. Based on the code you already have I think you should write a **method** that will return desired string.

```
const displayNameButton = (project) => {
  return (project.wordpress === 'yes') ? 'See Website' : 'See code';
})
```

and in the template

```
    <a
      :href="project.link"
      target="_blank"
      class="app__projects__content-btn"
    >
      {{ displayNameButton(project) }}
    </a>
```

*OR* you can modify your *visibleProjects*:

```
const visibleProjects = computed(() => {
  return storeProjects.projects.slice(0, maxProjectsShown.value).map((e) => {      
    const project = {...e};
    project.wordpress = (project.wordpress === 'yes') ? 'See Website' : 'See code';
    return project;
  });
});
```

and in the template

```
    <a
      :href="project.link"
      target="_blank"
      class="app__projects__content-btn"
    >
      {{ project.wordpress }}
    </a>
```

Comment: Yup. It's working.

Comment: I also added an additional solution, you can choose which one better suits you

Comment: Do you have any idea when I'm trying to select the hr element from the template that I wrote above and trying to apply it to the last child of a CSS property the CSS gets applied to all elements?

hr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb !important;
}

hr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

Output: I want to remove the border bottom for the hr element the last child from the template.

Comment: Because __:last-child__ applies CSS to the last child of every parent separately - and because every _hr_ is the last and only child of _div_ it will apply CSS to every one of them

Comment: [Explanations with example](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I fix that?

Comment: I am not sure but about something like that div > div:last-child > div > hr { border-bottom: none !important; }